# SQL store different type of questions structure suggestion?

Tags: database-design

I am trying to find a suitable way to store questions of different types and the answers for each of them. To be more specific, the question types I want to store are:

1) Multiple choice type

2) Yes/No type

3) Fill the gap type

4) Matching elements type (match elements from the column A to the elements of column B)

My idea so far was to do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Question (
    QuestionID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionText varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    QuestionType varchar(255),
    CorrectAnswer varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (QuestionID)
);

CREATE TABLE Answer (
    AnswerID int NOT NULL,
    AnswerText varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AnswerID)
);

CREATE TABLE QuestionToAnswer (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Question(QuestionID),
    AnswerID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Answer(AnswerID),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Although, the implementation above cannot cover the fourth question type.

Any suggestion/help, is welcome!

Comment: I would have expected some way of identifying the person that gave an answer `answer` table. And if the combination of `(questionid, answerid)` is considered unique the `id` column in `questiontoanswer` is useless. You can remove it and declare `(questionid, answerid)` as the primary key

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for that although Questions AND Answers have to be predefined.

Comment: Problem here is that your questions with type `1, 2 and 3` have actually 1 correct answer and your matching elements type has `multiple correct answers`, so ether you have to repeat data in Question table, or create new table that will represent `CorrectAnswers`

Comment: @Veljko89 That is correct, thnaks. So, this is why I am wondering for the most efficient way that could cover all the question type cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that allows a template of multiple source elements per question and multiple target elements for each source element

1 Introduce a QuestionType table and point the Question at this. This will ensure you only use valid values, remove redundancy, and enable you to use the QuestionType table for logic control.

2 Add a table for Users and provide a foreign key in the Answer table pointing to the User. This will enable you to identify the users.

3 To accommodate your 4th requirement, you will need something like this:

```
-- provides a list of possible alternatives from which to match
CREATE TABLE AnswerElement(
    AnswerElementID int NOT NULL,
    ElementName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AnswerElementID)
);

--provides the question elements that need to be matched
CREATE TABLE QuestionElement(
    QuestionElementID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Question(QuestionID),
    ElementToMatchID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AnswerElement(AnswerElementID),
    PRIMARY KEY (QuestionElementID)


--provides the candidate answer matches. 
CREATE TABLE ElementMatchAnswer(
    ElementMatchAnswerID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Question(QuestionID),
    UserID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User(UserID), 
    ElementtoMatchID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AnswerElement(AnswerElementID),
    MatchingElementID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AnswerElement(AnswerElementID),
    PRIMARY KEY ElementMatchAnswerID

--provides the correct answers
CREATE TABLE QuestionElementCorrectAnswer(
    QuestionElementCorrectAnswerID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Question(QuestionID),
    ElementToMatchID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AnswerElement(AnswerElementID),
    MatchingElementID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES     AnswerElement(AnswerElementID),
    PRIMARY KEY (QuestionElementCorrectAnswerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could go for a start ... you don't need tables as `Answer` and `QuestionToAnswer`, for every question created you insert record in `SubQuestion` or call it `PossibleAnswers` or something, how you ever you find easier to understand it.

```
CREATE TABLE Question (
    QuestionID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionText varchar(255) NOT NULL, -- here is question like 
                                        -- 'Do you drink coffee in evenings?', then 
                                        -- in SubQuestion table youll have rows 
                                        -- for 'Yes' / 'No'
    QuestionTypeID  INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES QuestionTypes(QuestionTypeID),
    PRIMARY KEY (QuestionID)
);

CREATE TABLE QuestionTypes (
    QuestionTypeID INT NOT NULL,        -- I would take QuestionType table separated
    QuestionDescription varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE SubQuestion (
    SubQuestionID int NOT NULL,         -- This table actually keeps possible answers 
                                        --  on your questions
    QuestionID int NOT NULL,
    QuestionText varchar(255) NOT NULL, -- Here you keep possible answers Yes / No, Maybe       
    CorrectAnswer varchar(255),         -- This should be bit 1 or 0 ... easier to 
                                        -- figure out which is correct answer
    PRIMARY KEY (SubQuestionID, QuestionID)
);
```

As someone needs to answer on these questions, then it gets easier for you to make table `UserAnswers` with columns

```
`UserId, QuestionId, AnsweredId -- which represent SubQuestionId`
```

Hope I made idea clear ...